# raspberry, switch between wifi and hotspot

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, wifi, hotspot

I am working on a raspberry for a POC demo.
My raspberry needs to be set up as a hotspot and that went fine following this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

However I can't get to easily switch between a "normal" wifi and the hotspot. I need to get back to a normal behavior to download packages to the raspberry for instance.
I found : http://sirlagz.net/2013/01/22/script-starting-hostapd-when-wifi-goes-down/ . Typing the same command does not seem to do the job.

What I've tried is :

- Raspberry set up as hotspot
- Stop dnsmasq and hostapd
- edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf (to remove the static ip configuration)
- restart dhcpd

I can see the raspberry is connected to the correct wifi but apparently I have no internet connection and can't download any packages.

Maybe there is something more to do about the iptables but I really don't know much about that and I prefer not screwing all my configuration.

Any idea about the procedure to switch between the two "modes"?

Cheers

Comment: Are you getting a correct ip address from dhcp server? Maybe you need to renew your address

Comment: Yes I have a correct IP address once I reconnect to the standard wifi.

Comment: Maybe check your default gateway. Maybe a trace route to see where are your packages stopping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution that works perfectly.

Disable access point :

- sudo systemctl disable hostapd dnsmasq
- comment the static ip config in /etc/dhcpcd.conf
- sudo reboot

Enable access point

- sudo systemctl enable hostapd dnsmasq
- comment the static IP config in /etc/dhcpcd.conf
- sudo reboot

The difference is instead of just stopping the 2 services I completely disable them.

Comment: To enable, I assume you meant "uncomment" on your second bullet.